# globus toolkit installation on ubuntu

Tags: globus-toolkit

I am trying to setup a grid by installing Globus Toolkit 6.0 on my ubuntu 16.04.
Steps given in Globus's website found to be little confusing. I followed steps given in another  website. 
I was using this command to install grid essential
wgethttp://www.globus.org/ftppub/gt6/installers/repo/globus-toolkit-
repo_latest_all.deb 
and I got the error message 404 not found.
When i check the link in globus i found  link is not presently available.
Is there any alternate ways to install this.
If anyone have solution of this problem, then please suggest, Or if you've any alternative steps to install and configure Globus Toolkit 6.0 on ubuntu16.04 please suggest...!

Answer (score 0):

From here , you can download globus toolkit repo debian package

www.globus.org/ftppub/gt6/installers/repo/globus-toolkit-repo_latest_all.deb

try here
[Globus toolkit](http://www.globus.org/ftppub/gt6/installers/repo/globus-toolkit-repo_latest_all.deb)